# Creating an event handler for the blur event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, blur

Trying to create a blur event that uses the event object's target property to get the input element on which the event is active. I added the code at the very bottom on what I thought was right but struggling to implement it without it screwing up the first part.

Also trying to put the `<script>` `</script>` in an external Javascript file, but when I try it doesn't work. Not sure if there's anything that depends on it being in the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="Username" minLength="6" 
maxlength="10" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="Password" minLength="8" maxlength="15" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function()">
</form> 

<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var textElements = [...document.getElementsByTagName('input')];
  var listen = function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev){
      if (event.target.validity.valid) {
          item.style.border = "solid green 2px";
          item.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px green";
      } else {
          item.style.border = "solid red 2px";
          item.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px red";
      }
    })
  }
  textElements.forEach(listen);
});

form.addEventListener('blur', function( event ) {
  event.target.style.border = "solid white 2px";
  event.target.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px white";
}, true);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understood correctly, but in my opinion, the problem is that the `form` element is not defined, at the time of assigning the `blur` event handler:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var textElements = [...document.getElementsByTagName('input')];
  var listen = function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev) {
      if (event.target.validity.valid) {
        item.style.border = "solid green 2px";
        item.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px green";
      } else {
        item.style.border = "solid red 2px";
        item.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px red";
      }
    })
  }
  textElements.forEach(listen);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  event.target.style.border = "solid white 2px";
  event.target.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px white";
}, true);
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" minLength="6" maxlength="10" required placeholder="Username">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" minLength="8" maxlength="15" required placeholder="Password">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function()">
</form>
```

If you do not need any additional checks, and you only need to visualize the correctness of the input, then you can do without JS:

```css
input {
  border: solid white 2px;
  boxShadow: 0 0 5px white;
}

input:focus:valid {
  border: solid green 2px;
  boxShadow: 0 0 5px green;
}

input:focus:invalid {
  border: solid red 2px;
  boxShadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" minLength="6" maxlength="10" required placeholder="Username">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" minLength="8" maxlength="15" required placeholder="Password">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed a lot of the other code as it was not really part of the question.

Switched to the `focusout` event as it bubbles.

You can adjust the `matches` filter to suit your needs.

Also I changed `white` to `red` for the demo as it didnt show :)

```js
document.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
  if(e.target.matches('input')) {
    e.target.style.border = "solid red 2px";
    e.target.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px red";    
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="Username" minLength="6" maxlength="10" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="Password" minLength="8" maxlength="15" required>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function()">
</form>
```

Here is a version with the full code you posted.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var textElements = [...document.getElementsByTagName('input')];
  var listen = function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev) {
      if (event.target.validity.valid) {
        item.style.border = "solid green 2px";
        item.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px green";
      } else {
        item.style.border = "solid red 2px";
        item.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px red";
      }
    })
  }
  textElements.forEach(listen);
});

document.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
  if (e.target.matches('input')) {
    e.target.style.border = "solid red 2px";
    e.target.style.boxShadow = "0 0 5px red";
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="Username" minLength="6" maxlength="10" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="Password" minLength="8" maxlength="15" required>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function()">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

For including your script.

Add a tag at the end of your HTML before the `</body>` tag.

Something like this:

`<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>`